# Unable to run even basic Node.Js file on raspberry pi

Tags: node.js, express, raspberry-pi

So I have installed node.js onto my raspberry pi. Checked that it was installed by running:

```
node -v
```

which yielded: 4.2.1 and

```
npm -v
```

which yielded 2.14.7. however when I try to run any .js file (that I have tested running in node on my pc) it fails with the following:

```
    pi@raspberrypi:~/share/Node $ node Brew-View.js 
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:80
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:874:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:897:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1221:19)
    at listen (net.js:1270:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1366:5)
    at EventEmitter.listen (/home/pi/share/Node/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:618:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/pi/share/Node/Brew-View.js:39:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

I even went back to basics and just ran a file that just had

```
console.log('Hello.');
```

in it and got the same result. This sounds like it is an issue being caused by a bad preinstalled module. but it is a fresh installation(both of node and raspbian). is there some setup step that you have to do specifically for node on pi or call it differently?
Note: this is on a pi 3 B+

Edit: this is  the code I am running which is yielding the 141 error(I have added ip and express to that directory via npm):

```
const express= require('express')
const ip = require('ip')


const ipAddr=ip.address();
const port=80;
const Server= express();
Server.use(express.static('public'))
Server.get('/',function(req,res){ 
    res.send('<html>'+
    '<head>'+
    '<meta charset ="UTF-8">'+
    '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./main.css"></head><body>'+
    '<h1>Brew View</h1>'+
    '<p>my IP is: '+ipAddr+":"+port+'</p>'+
    '</body>'+
    '</html>')
})

 // Handle 404
 Server.use(function(req, res) {
    res.status(404).send('<html>'+
    '<head>'+
    '<meta charset ="UTF-8">'+
    '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./main.css"></head><body>'+
    '<h1>404: Page not Found</h1>'+
    '</body>'+
    '</html>');
 });

 // Handle 500
 Server.use(function(error, req, res, next) {
    res.send('500: Internal Server Error', 500);
 });

Server.use(express.static('public'))
Server.listen(80,()=> console.log("Hello. Brew View is Hosted at: "+ipAddr+":"+port))
```

this was also occurring with a more basic http module based server as well.

Edit: so The solution was that you can't automatically host on port 80 without root.

Comment: Seems weird that a simple `console.log()` would request access to port 80. What was the stack trace for running that particular file?

Comment: no. and actually now I retried a basic file and it now works.. :/

Comment: Your `Brew-View.js` is attempting to open a server on port 80. Either change to a non-reserved port (greater than 1024) or run as root.

Comment: I just tried setting the port to 8080 and 48000 and both yielded the same error. is there something I need to do to open up those ports explicitly?

Comment: you set `port` to `8080`, or the first argument of `Server.listen()` to `8080`?

Comment: After further review it looks like I had hard coded 80 as the port for the Server.Listen(). Post an answer and I will accept it as best answer.